# unsure where to put Stripe API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Been thinking about this problem for hours now, and I think it's because im misunderstanding some fundamental rails knowledge

In [this intro Stripe guide](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/rails), they demonstrates the following code

```
def new
end

def create
  # Amount in cents
  @amount = 500

  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => 'example@stripe.com',
    :card  => params[:stripeToken]
  )

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount      => @amount,
    :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
    :currency    => 'usd'
  )

rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to charges_path
end
```

My question is, do all the code in the `create` action have to reside within `create`?

I am trying to follow through with the guide, but instead of only having one single product, I have multiples. So naturally I put the code within the `show` action.

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @books = Book.all
    end

    def show
        @book = Book.find(params[:id])


        customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
            :email => 'example@stripe.com',
            :card  => params[:stripeToken]
        )

        charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
            :customer    => customer.id,
            :amount      => @book.price,
            :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
            :currency    => 'usd'
        )

        rescue Stripe::CardError => e
            flash[:error] = e.message
            redirect_to books_path

    end
end
```

Now, whenever I try to access any show page (localhost:3000/books/1), it redirects to the `books_path`, which tells me there is some kind of CardError.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are confusing / mixing some rails knowledge. What you need to do is:

```
#Create your BooksController
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @book = Book.all
  end

  def new
    @book = Book.new
  end 

  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)
      if @book.save
        #do something
      else
        #do something
      end
  end

  def show
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end

   #edit
   #destroy    
end
```

Then, separately, you would create your stripe transaction; this could be in a controller called `Sales`.

```
#Create your SalesController
class SalesController < ApplicationController


  def create
    @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
      #stripe create code using book attributes (@book.price)



   #after sale in stripe. create record in a sales table.

   Sale.create(book_id: @book.id, amount: @book.price, other stuff)

  end

end
```

You would need to nest your `sales` actions within your book actions in your routes file.

```
resources: books do 
  resources :sales
end
```

That should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Two questions, do I need the `Sale.create(book_id: @book.id, amount: @book.price, other stuff)` line since it the Stripe guide doesn't appear to have a database also. Second, I followed your suggestion and nested the salescontroller. Everything seems fine on my end, but the dashboard isn't actually showing any charges. Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, you need to create the Sale on your end if you want a record of it (other than Stripe). Stripe does have a database that you can reference. You need to store the stripe keys with the object. So for example, if a user is logged in, you can store a stripe customer id to that user model. Then, you can retrieve all transactions attached to that customer.

Comment: Do you have a js file creating your stripe token?

Answer (score 1):

Because you have this in your `show` method:

```
   rescue Stripe::CardError => e
        flash[:error] = e.message
        redirect_to books_path
```

When you try to access any page by `show` action, it tries to create the `charge` and got an error so it's rescued by the above code and you are redirected to the `books_path`. So, this is pretty normal behaviour.

If you fix the `CardError` that you're getting, it will create the charge successfully. But, again, this is not the right place to create the charge.
You should have a custom controller/view as shown in the tutorial itself, to create the charge.

In your show page, you can have a form for product and a button for purchasing the product, when the button is pressed, your form should be submitted to the custom controller's action method where you create the charge.